# HTML let site have always the same size

Tags: html, css

I want to know if you can let your site always be at the same size so when you view the site on a bigger screen, it just adds more space/background to the page.

(I don't want media queries so that the style changes when the screen gets bigger)

Comment: You can do that easily by setting static width and height for your main element. However, it is not a good approach because it will make your site too small on large screens or too large on small screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS you can center your main div (wrapper).

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  background: green;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

#wrapper {
  width: auto; /* You can set the width here, but if you want to make the page smaller on smaller devices you use 'auto' here. */
  max-width: 500px; /* Set the maximum width of the webpage. */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Center the wrapper */
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h1>Welcome to your webpage.</h1>
    <h2>Site content goes here.</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This answer the question.

Comment: Thanx for your answer.